# unable to access variable in function

Tags: php, sql, scope

I am separating calling script and the query script 
index.php:

```
require_once('./connection.php');

findAll('user');
```

and my connection.php contains

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', "root", "", "test");
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

function findAll($tableName){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tableName";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       echo "<pre>";print_R($row);echo "</pre>";
    }
}
```

but it return an error message

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in
>   F:\wamp\www\scaff\connection.php on line 9

code on line no 9:

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

can you please help me to find reason why it is not getting access to global function

Comment: pass 1 more parameter $conn to    function findAll($tableName, $conn)

Comment: my problem solve by using global , here is ref:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060465/get-variables-from-the-outside-inside-a-function-in-php

Comment: yes you can declare that as global ...or just pass the parameter